# Deezer API fail request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, request, deezer

i'm trying to consume deezer api, but idk how to do it.
I already read the documentation, learn how I can get my token, but when I'm trying to request i got this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.deezer.com/album/302127' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

how can I solve this?
url: https://api.deezer.com/album/302127

idk the problem with my request.

```
async function getAlbum() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.deezer.com/album/302127", {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
      }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
getAlbum();
```

Comment: Are you requesting it from your browser? Your React app?

Comment: yes, I'm trying the browser

Comment: So, the error message indicates that your origin is for some reason `'null'`. If this is a public API, they most likely allowed any origins to access it, but since your origin is somehow `'null'`, it's not working, I think. Can you check your Network tab and see if there's anything weird?